# How to load JSON result into listview

Tags: java, android, json

I am new on Android and Java. Can any one tell me how can I load json result that i get from http request from URL to ListView. In below onpostExecute I get the result but have no idea how to load it on a listview.

```
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
                etResponse.setText(json.getString("name"));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
```

Here is my ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Main ListView 
         Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
    -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/test_list_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

For an example my Json looks like this:
{
id: "1",
name: "Any name",
email: "Any Email"
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What does your JSON look like, we cannot really guess you know. you havent show any relevant code

Comment: i have a tutorial here : http://njzk2.wordpress.com/2013/08/06/json-to-listview/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json data that you converted to string must be different things as for ex. blog posts so what you can do is convert into into a jsonArray and loop over the array grabbing each json object from array and assigning the values to listview. Do you need the actual code or the logic?

```
String jsonres = '{
id: "1",
name: "Any name",
email: "Any Email"
}';
```

You would do something like:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
JSONObject myJsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonres);
ListView mylv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylvID);
HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
Sring id = myJsonObject.getString("id");
String name = myJsonObject.getString("name");
String email = myJsonObject.getString("email");

item.put("id", id);
item.put("name", name);
item.put("email", email);

items.add(item);
String[] keys = {"id", "name", "email"};//our keys for which we take the corresponding value
int[] ids = {R.id.title, R.id.author, R.id.date};

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, items, R.layout.list_view_item, keys, ids);
mylv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

//list_view_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainListActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.85"
            android:gravity="left">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/blogPostImage"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
        </TableLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:gravity="right">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Large Text is a very large and long text"
                    android:id="@+id/title" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="Author's Name"
                        android:id="@+id/author"
                        android:layout_weight="0.7"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="2014-15-16 14:15:16"
                        android:id="@+id/date"
                        android:layout_weight="0.3"
                        android:gravity="right"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I also suggest reading more about listadapters as that will help you understand what you are doing better.

Comment: I have tried to loop through jsonArray and add each data to ArrayList and then load it to the adapter but it seem this will not work on AssyncTask.

Comment: Are you trying to do this inside the doInBackground method. You cannot do it inside there because that runs on a separate thread thus you would do this in onPostExecute. I suggest creating a global JsonObject variable and return your data as a jsonObject in doInBackground. Then you can create a method to convert into array and fill you listview.

Comment: Thank you @gurinderhans for fast response, I have loaded json result into arraylist. BUT the question is how to load the arraylist to the adapter.

Comment: Updated answer again please check again :) You'll have to rename stuff.

Comment: Thank you bro :) Not what I wanted but I got the idea.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I helped in some way.